# Java JAAS authentication requires database port number

Tags: java, url, tomcat, postgresql-9.1, jaas

Hi im using the this [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/java-jaas-form-based-authentication.html) for the Java JAAS form based authentication,

implementation of JAAS login module validates the user entered user name and password with the database(postgresql)

in JAAS We should create ‘jass.config’ file and should be placed that file under ‘`$CATALINA_HOME/conf`‘(Tomcat)

my question is jass.config need the database(postgresql) port number?
 without port number we can access the database(postgresql)?

any help will be appreciated.. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

The port number must be specified if it isn't the default.

That's true of any URL. It has nothing to do with Tomcat or servlets or JAAS or PostgresSQL or JSP specifically.

Comment: the postgresql has default port number 5432.. are you sure i required port number while we are connecting via jaas?

Comment: @SathishSiva I can only suggest you read my answer again. I didn't say what you are now asking me to confirm.